# Wrapping C++ with Python - Returning References

Tags: python, c++, boost, swig

I'm looking to wrap a small C++ library for use in Python. I've briefly read up on the Python C-API, ctypes, Cython, SWIG, Boost.Python, and CLIF. Which framework (or other) should I use given my specific use-case described below?

**Context:** I have a multi-process program that does communication via [shared memory](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html). I've written `Writer` and `Reader` classes to interact with the shared memory and handle synchronization. I have multiple C++ programs working together via the shared memory and want to add a Python program to the party. Its behavior in interacting with the shared memory should be the same as the C++ programs.

**Considerations:**

- (main) The data packets stored in the shared memory are *large*, so I want to *avoid a copy* when returning to Python. Specifically, the `Reader::read()` method returns a `const T&` reference so the client can directly read from it. I'd like to preserve this behavior in the Python class.
- Would like to directly expose the `Writer()` and `Reader()` classes as Python classes without re-implementing logic.
- I'm only exposing these two classes, not an entire library. I don't mind some upfront work if it means more maintainability.
- All things being equal, I'd like to minimize external dependencies. That said, I don't mind dependencies if it leads to a better outcome.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and congrats on making your first post. You'll get better answers and more upvotes if you make your question very clear. You've said what you're trying to accomplish, but it's not clear what you're actually *asking* here -- there should be a question, complete with a question mark (`?`). Writing the specific question down will make this post more focussed and less likely to be closed for being unclear. Good luck!

Comment: What types, T do you actually care about here? For many you'll have no choice but to make a copy when you return to python because that's how python works. You can return memory views instead, but at some point they still have to get copied to a python type really. It's really not clear what you're trying to do here, if you want performance and no copies then creating a python wrapper isn't going to help.